# Resizing image to fill background regardless of page height and width (while maintaining correct ratio)

Tags: javascript, css, scaling

I have a background that works as a random image each time the page loads.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="images">
    <img id="background" height="100%" width="auto"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#background {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var imgs=["/backgrounds/1.jpg","/backgrounds/2.jpg","/backgrounds/3.jpg","/backgrounds/4.jpg","/backgrounds/5.jpg"]var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*imgs.length)onload=function() {background.src = imgs[rand]}// JavaScript Document</script>
```

The problem is that as soon as the image (which is not a background but within the div), which is in landscape ratio, switches to 100% due to "min-height: "100%", I need the width to change to "auto", how do I achieve this? Cheers, Steff

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css background image and set:

```
background-size: cover;
```